# How to avoid opening screen multiple times?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

[video with bug](https://media-upload.net/uploads/4QBLqZIXfMeA.mp4)
My app architecture looks like: viewModel + Compose layout per screen. In my viewModels  I have Channel() where I handle actions from screen:

```
init {
  viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                actions.receiveAsFlow().collect { action ->
                    when (action) {
                                    //handle actions here
                   }
              }
        }
}
```

In Home screen I have list with post. The problem is when I select post and navigate user to PostDetails screen I can choose another post though list with post is underhood. I think it's related to Home viewModel and that action flow works in the background. Any solution what should I change?

```
@Composable
fun AppNavigationHost(appNavController: NavController) {
NavHost(
    navController = appNavController as NavHostController,
    startDestination = PostDetails.route
) {
    composable(Default.route) {}

    composable(PostDetails.route) { it ->
        it.arguments?.getString("post").let {
            val post = Gson().fromJson(it, Post::class.java)
            PostDetailsScreen(post, appNavController)
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar problems before, albeit not using compose. If you don't set a dialog to be clickable then you can click through it. I would suggest adding:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

To the UI you're using for the post details, or the compose equivalent

Comment: In Compose "clickable" is set to true as default